# Wordpress Pagination Not Working On Custom Page Template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I cannot get pagination links to appear on a custom page template.  I have followed the Wordpress docs and have made this work before but for some reason the following code won't output the pagination links.

```
<?php
  $paged = ( get_query_var('paged') ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
    'category_name' => 'press-releases',
    'paged' => $paged,
  );
  $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
  if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
    get_template_part( 'content', get_post_format() );
  endwhile; 
?>
<div class="previous-posts">
  <?php next_posts_link('Previous Posts'); ?>
</div>
<div class="newer-posts">
  <?php previous_posts_link('Newer Posts'); ?>
</div>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

Hoping another set of eyes on this can spot an issue and help find a fix.

Thank You!

Comment: What does it output and what are you expecting it to output?

Comment: did you try that : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/paginate_links it works for me.

Comment: That didn't work either.  The pagination links will not appear below the blog loop.